# How to change ListViews state_focus and state_pressed colors

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out without any success.

I am basically trying to change the color of my list items when they are clicked.

i have made a selector xml file and stored it in res/color/red_background.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000">
</item> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

then i have tried changing the listview color to transparent in list.xml and in main.xml i used the android:listselector attribute in my listview and passed in the red_background to it.

```
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/main_list"
android:listSelector="@color/red_background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
></ListView>
```

everytime i run the program it force closes if i remove "android:listSelector="@color/red_background" the program runs fine.

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive that by 2 steps as below:

**Step1**: Move color to color.xml resource file:

```
<color name="color_list_press">#ffff0000</color>
<color name="color_list_focused">#ff0000ff</color>
<color name="color_list_default">#ff000000</color>
```

**Step2:** Change from android:color to android:drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/color_list_press"/>

    <!-- focused --> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@color/color_list_focused"/>

      <!-- default --> 
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_list_default"/>
</selector>
```

Regards,

Comment: Yea, dont think that will work, unless i am doing something wrong, but i moved the colors to another file and assumed you said to change "android:color="@color/color_list_press" to "android:drawable="@color/color_list_press" but i cant call the color state after the "@color/..." i can only call the whole xml file. again i could be doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i miss typing in code snippet of selector, In selector file: change android:color to android:drawable

Comment: in step one, am i supposed to make 3 different xml color files in the color folder? because right now i have all the states in one file.

Comment: You only need add 3 colors define to color.xml, is it OK ? Otherwise, i have little confuse: this setting will change background of ListView, is it your expected ?

Comment: yes, thats what i was missing, i didnt make a color.xml file, its working now, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Its also worth mentioning for people that are looking for a solution to this, make sure to place the color.xml file inside the "values" folder, where strings.xml is, for some reason when i had color.xml file in color folder it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `android:listSelector="@drawable/red_background"` in your listview and you need to put red_background.xml in drawable folder